# How to customise synthetic PodFile IN KMM shared library

Tags: cocoapods, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am facing some problem to build kmm shared library. It was due to platform version.
here is my podspec file

shared/build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'shared'
    spec.version                  = '1.0'
    spec.homepage                 = 'Link to the Shared Module homepage'
    spec.source                   = { :http=> ''}
    spec.authors                  = ''
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'Test'
    spec.vendored_frameworks      = 'build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework'
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '14.1'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseAppCheck'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseAuth'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseCore'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseFirestore'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseMessaging'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseStorage'
    spec.dependency 'SQLCipher'
                
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':shared',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'shared',
    }
                
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build shared',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
                
end
```

Generated podfile in .../shared/build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org'
target 'ios' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseAppCheck'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
    pod 'FirebaseStorage'
    pod 'SQLCipher'
end
```

is there anyway i can modify this file (not manual) like this

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org'
target 'ios' do
    use_frameworks!
    platform :ios, '14.1'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseAppCheck'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
    pod 'FirebaseStorage'
    pod 'SQLCipher'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    puts target.name
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.1'
       config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'Yes'
       config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf-with-dsym'
       config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem after upgrading Xcode from 14.2 to 14.3 and I got here while trying to find a solution.

As you state you have to update the autogenerated `project.pbxproj` files in your shared build folder. You can do it by adding a new task to your shared code `build.gradle.kts` script. Something like:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<PodGenTask>().configureEach {
    doLast {

        val xcodeprojFiles = listOf(
            "Pods/Pods.xcodeproj",
            "synthetic.xcodeproj",
        )

        for (xcodeprojFile in xcodeprojFiles) {
            val file = project.buildDir.resolve("cocoapods/synthetic/${family.name}/$xcodeprojFile/project.pbxproj")
            setIosDeploymentTarget(file)
        }
    }
}
```

This script will process:

- `build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
- `build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS/synthetic.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

Make sure these are the files you need to process or update the file list properly to match your project configuration.

You will also to provide the `setIosDeploymentTarget` function, of course:

```kotlin
fun Project.setIosDeploymentTarget(
    xcodeprojFile: File,
    source: String = "10.0",
    target: String = "14.1",
) {
    val lines = xcodeprojFile.readLines()
    val out = xcodeprojFile.bufferedWriter()
    out.use {
        for (line in lines) {
            out.write(line.replace("IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = $source;", "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = $target;"))
            out.write(("\n"))
        }
    }
}
```

The function takes two additional parameters `source` and `target` which default to `"10.0"` and `"14.1"` respectively.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-57741

Hope it helps.